# Determine if a number is power of 4, logNum % logBase == 0 vs (logNum / logBase) % 1 == 0

Tags: java, algorithm

Problem: check if a number is a power of 4.

my solution in java:

```
public static boolean isPowerOfFour(int num) {
    return (Math.log(num) % Math.log(4) == 0);
}
```

But it seems off in some cases, for example when num is 64.

I found out that if I change the code a little bit, it works well.

```
public static boolean isPowerOfFour(int num) {
    return (Math.log(num) / Math.log(4) %1 == 0);
}
```

I think both solutions do the same thing, check if the remaining of logNum/logBase is 0. But why the first solution doesn't work? Is it because the solution is incorrect or relative to some low level JVM stuff?
Thanks.

Comment: you're using floating point numbers. treat them like the Borg. "We are Float of Borg. Accuracy is irrelevant. You Will be Approximated". in float, `log(64) / log(4)` comes out to 2.9999999999, meaning the modulo is non-zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on @dasblinkenlight's answer, you can easily combine both conditions (first, a power of 2, then any power of 4 among all possible powers of 2) with a simple mask:

```
public static boolean isPowerOfFour(int num) {
  return ((( num & ( num - 1 )) == 0 )    // check whether num is a power of 2
      &&  (( num & 0xaaaaaaaa ) == 0 ));  // make sure it's an even power of 2
}
```

No loop, no conversion to float.

Comment: Checking for bits set in odd positions with an `& 0xaaaaaaaa`? That's a really beautiful idea!

Comment: Thanks for the great idea and the amazing solution!!! BTW, I have a question about my ugly solution up there. I tried to print out Math.log(64) % Math.log(4), and I got 1.38..... Print out (Math.log(64) / Math.log(4), and  I got 3.0. Both of them are double and double operations, but why the result is so different? (1 decimal point vs tons of decimal points)

Answer (score 1):

Checking if a number is a power of 4 is the same as checking that the number is an even power of 2.

You can check that a number `x` is a power of two by verifying that `x & (x-1)` is zero ([here is the explanation of how this works](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2))

If your number is *not* a power of 2, return `false`. Otherwise, shift the number right until you get to one, and count the number of shifts. If you shifted an odd number of times, return `false`; otherwise, return `true`:

```
public static boolean isPowerOfFour(int num) {
    if ((num & (num-1)) != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    int count = 0;
    while (num != 1) {
        num >>= 1;
        count++;
    }
    return count % 2 == 0;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/tKoxck)

Answer (score 0):

Functions like Math.log return floating point numbers with a rounding error. So when num = 64 for example, Math.log (num) / Math.log (4) is not exactly 3, but a number close to 3.

```
public static boolean isPowerOfFour(int num) {
    if (num > 0) {
        while (num % 4 == 0) num /= 4;
    }
    return (num == 1);
}
```

This solution can be quite easily adapted to check whether num is a power of some other integer greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because Math.log() returns a double.  The answer of `false` is reflective of rounding errors; log(64) base e is an irrational number but Java needs to truncate it to fit it's width.